# Use of node vs custom eck entity bundle

Tags: entities

Is there a difference in weight (performance wise) in using custom *eck entity bundles* or *nodes*?

So if I need to store data bundles with the following values(fields):

- Entity Reference to other node nr 1.
- Entity Reference to other node nr 2.
- Boolean

Now when there will be more than 100.000 of these data bundles is there any difference in performance when using the core nodes or a custom eck entity bundle when for example using views to this information or when I use search to go through the data?

Comment: 1 of the key differences is nodes are mainly geared up to be viewable pages so come with extra fields and options to cater for that. Do you need these entities to be viewable? Or if its simply as a storage option to hold data then ECK would be the way to go. But essentially both are drupal entities and you can access them just the same way in views

Comment: This is a content modeling question. Is it content? Node. Is it _not_ content? Its not a node.

Comment: One more question about this...considering ECK is still in alpha for Drupal 8 is it still smart to use ECK over nodes?